# Clear text boxes in parent fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this ["Fancy Slider"](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/) plugin which works by basically setting a number of fieldsets side by side. Since each fieldset is a member of the same class, I'm trying to find the easiest way to add a clear button for each form and, using jQuery, clear the input fields in that particular form alone.

I've tried using `.parent()`, `.parents()`, and `.closest()` to isolate the fieldset the user is working on with no luck. While I can clear the form I'm working on, I wind up clearing the form in every fieldset in the app. We use jQuery every so often so I'm relatively new to this. Any ideas?

**jQuery**

```
    $('#clearButton').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input:text').val('');
        $('#Pensgc').attr('readonly', false);
    });
```

**Sample Razor**

```
<fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Display Exceptions</legend>
    <center>
        <table id="ExceptionEditing">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Exception Name</th>
                    <th>Starting Letter</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExceptionList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr id="@Model.ExceptionList[i].Id">
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(anything => Model.ExceptionList[i].ExceptionName, new {style = "width:300px;", @readonly = "readonly", maxlength=255 })
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left:30px;" class="EditStartingLetter">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(anything => Model.ExceptionList[i].StartingLetter, new {style = "width:10px;", @readonly = "readonly", maxlength=1 })
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a href="#" class="editException">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a href="#" class="deleteException">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="step">
    <center>
        <legend>Create Exception</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.createExceptionName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.createExceptionName, new { @class="AlphaNumOnly", maxlength=255 })
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.createExceptionLetter)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.createExceptionLetter, new { @class="AlphaNumOnly", maxlength=1 })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>
        <button type="submit" class="clearButton">Clear</button>
    </center>
</fieldset>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rZa2j/

Comment: Working jsfiddle helps us help you

Comment: Your selector is wrong compared to your HTML.  You are using `#clearButton` which is an ID.  In your HTML, you have `class="clearButton"`.

Comment: Post the generated html please

Comment: @NealR Kyle has the answer. You're selecting the button by ID, but It has only the class.

Comment: @MikeBell - just added a fiddle

Comment: @Kyle - For some reason the `ID` selector was working regardless. I switched to the `class` and got the same results. Just posted a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation, I've found the following line's in their JavaScript:

```
current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
```

with $this referring to the  clicked. That means: If the second tab is opened, current will be 1.

```
var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;
```

That's the way they're retrieving the amount of slides.
By putting everything together, you could get the current fieldset by using this code:

```
var currentFieldsetIndex = $(".selected").index();
var $currentFieldset = $("#formElem").children().eq(currentFieldsetIndex);
```

and then you can extend your function with

```
$currentFieldset.find("input:text").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I'd set the `type` attribute to `reset`. Have never used this before, however removing it fixed the problem.

```
<button class="clearButton">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Was just about to post this answer.  Using `reset` and `submit` will cause the form to take its default action when clicked.  To avoid this, you can use `evt.preventDefault()` in your click function to ensure that the form doesn't do it's native `reset` and `submit` actions.